# Where to store several files with big download traffic?

Tags: cloud, storage, file-storage

Could you please help me: I have music mobile app, this app downloads some files from server/storage (currently it's Dropbox and Google Drive). But these services have limits for downloading traffic and they block files after exceeding this limit.

My average numbers are following:
* One file is about 10 Mb. 
* One file can be downloaded 2000 times per day
So one file can be downloaded 60 000 times per month, it's about 600 Gb per month.

Currently I have 5 files, but every one or two month I'm going to add new file. Actually the number of downloads can be increased or decreased, 2000 per day is average number.

Could you please advice where I must store my files? 
I don't need any php-scripts or something like that. Just URL which can be opened to download one zip file.

I've checked Rackspace, but it's too expensive for my free app :) Their calculator gives me the price $1200 per month.
Dropbox has limit in 200 Gb per day (paid account), it's also not enough for several files.
Google drive doesn't show any limits, but they've already block one my file that was downloaded about 2000 times.

The best solution I've found now is dedicated server, $180 per month with 10Tb bandwidth (it should be enough for 10-16 files).

But may be you guys know better solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should use object store services. Most known are [AWS S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/), [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/pricing/cloud-storage), [Rackspace Cloud Files](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/files/pricing/). All would be about $72 for transfer, storage and number of requests doesn't add much here. But there are other providers who provide similar solutions, like [e24cloud](http://www.e24cloud.com/en/Solutions/Cloud-Files#conf), where it would cost you just $6 per month.

Obviously there are also number of free solutions like [RapidShare](https://rapidshare.com) but these don't provide nice experience for your users (need to wait longer for download or pay, advertisements, etc.).